# dynamic adding images in wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

i am working with my footer to add many images in my wordpress theme, I want it to be dynamic in my dashboard. In my code i have many image src with an id of divimg where i added my images static.

all i want is to make the image something like a loop or any to have a selection in my wordpress admin dashboard menu to upload images and it will be added in that div. Please provide me some to add in functions.php and call it in my div with `img src id = divimg`

here is my static code :

```
<section id ="brand">
            <div id="wrapper">
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/atlanta.png" />
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/atmor.png" />
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/bestank.png" />
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/ebsray.png" />
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/era.png" />
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/firefly.png" />
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/fsl.png" />
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/joven.png" />
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/meijia.png" />
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/omni.png" />
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/panasonic.png" />
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/royu.png" />
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/state.png" />
                    <img id="divimg" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/thermo.png" />
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any plugin: -

please check this widget

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-widget/screenshots/
```

you can add this widget from backend to the footer and add the images dynamically .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but I use "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin for stuff like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/